# Instrumentation and Tomcat Hotdeploy

Tags: java, tomcat7, instrumentation, javaagents

I'm working on a Java agent to instrument some application classes and getting runtime information. When I redeploy my application on Tomcat 7, I loose most of my instrumented classes and no method in my agent is called for reinstrumenting the new loaded classes.

How can I capture newly loaded classes to instrument them? Or is there a way to capture redeploy event to start a `getAllLoadedClasses` and reinstrument everything?

Any better way to solve the problem is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When redeploying an application, Tomcat releaves the class loader for the undeployed application. This way, all classes can be unloaded by the JVM that runs Tomcat. At the same time, the application is loaded again by another class loader, all classes of the redeployed application are therefore loaded for the first time.

You can therefore simply intercept the loading procedure using a `ClassFileTransformer` and instrument all classes without redefining any class. The `ClassFileTransformer` is triggered for any class loaded by Tomcat.